# matplotlib drawing contour labels outside AxesSubplot in .eps file

Tags: python, matplotlib, eps

I am making a plot using matplotlib.pyplot imported as PL:

```
FIG = PL.figure(figsize=(12,8), dpi=150)
AX = FIG.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal', xlim=(lonMin,lonMax), ylim=(latMin,latMax))
PL.contourf(lon, lat, swath, range(2,56,1))
PL.colorbar(shrink=0.8, extend='both', ticks=range(5,55,5))
CNTR = PL.contour(lon, lat, rain, colors='black', linewidths=1)
PL.clabel(CNTR, fmt='%2i', inline_spacing=2)
PL.savefig('swaths_ao.png', bbox_inches='tight')
PL.savefig('swaths_ao.eps', bbox_inches='tight')
PL.savefig('swaths_ao.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
PL.clf()
```

The problem that I have is that PL.clabel draws contour labels even outside limits of AX, that is, in the whitespace of FIG. This happens only in .eps file, but not for .png or .pdf. Coincidentally, I need .eps.

Any hints on how to remedy this?

Comment: Is there a special reason to import `pyplot as PL` ?. Why not the conventional `plt`. Frankly it looks weird. Same for `FIG`.

Comment: You could check `Naming Conventions` for constants and variables in [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug you could file as [an issue on Github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues), but as a workaround, if pdf output looks correct, you could use pdftops (comes with xpdf) and then [ps2eps](http://www.tm.uka.de/~bless/ps2eps).

Comment: Thanks, this is certainly a workaround for now. I will update if I find out anything.